# No module named pymindwave

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, mindwave

I have installed pymindwave in the following directory:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

However when I run another code which depends on it it says it can't find pymindwave. What's the solution?

[image]

Here's the first few lines of the code that gives the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import platform
import sys, time
from pymindwave import headset
import httplib, urllib, urllib2
import json
```

And I have taken [the code](https://github.com/lab11/mindwave) and [python_mindwave](https://github.com/akloster/python-mindwave) from these links.

P.S.: I am not a Windows person but MindWave doesn't get recognized in OSX so I am forcefully using Windows 8.1 enterprise edition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing `mindwave` instead of `pymindwave`.

Comment: When I do so, it says "ImportError: cannot import name headset" any idea what I should do? Thanks

Comment: Hey thank you that fixed that error but I wonder if you are looking at an API? Now it tells me no module named Bluetooth in bluetooth_headset.py is there a correct version of mindwave for python I should have download?

Comment: @MonaJalal I'm just looking at the Github link you posted. In there you will see a hierarchy: `python-mindwave/mindwave/bluetooth_headset.py`. That's how I knew.

Comment: can you please take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168384/after-installing-pybluez-on-windows8-1-i-get-dll-1-not-valid-win32-app